# using wait in pywinauto times out but sleep works fine

Tags: python, pywinauto

I am trying to automate some GUI stuff in Windows. I open a settings window but when waiting for it to open before continuing, it times out:

```
from pywinauto import Application

app = Application()
app.start(r"explorer shell:::{05d7b0f4-2121-4eff-bf6b-ed3f69b894d9}")
app.window(title_re=".*Notification Area Icons*").wait("exists", timeout=20)
app = Application(backend="uia").connect(title_re=".*Notification Area Icons*")

main_dlg = app.window(title_re=".*Notification Area Icons*")
main_dlg.print_control_identifiers()
```

Even with the timeout at 20 seconds, it times out. However, if I replace `app.window(title_re=".*Notification Area Icons*").wait("exists", timeout=20)` with `sleep(5)` (and add the appropriate import) it works fine. I know the window title is correct because it will print out the control ids when using `sleep`. I've tried using "exists" and "visible" for the wait as well. I think the other options are more strict so I'm not sure why the wait is not working.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible there are few `explorer.exe` processes. You can try process-agnostic way:

```
from pywinauto import Desktop
window_wrapper = Desktop(backend="uia").window(title_re=".*Notification Area Icons*").wait("exists", timeout=20)
print(window_wrapper.process_id())
# and compare with print(app.process)
```